# Pair Programming - Cannot access Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-vpc

I am fairly new to AWS and have used the guides/QnA here to debug my issue. But I am certainly missing something as my Lambda fails to access the internet when setup inside my VPC. Could anyone please eyeball my setup and advice on what's wrong?

VPC Subnets
[image: VPC Subnets]

Public Route Table
[image: Public Route Table]

Private Route Table
[image: Private Route Table]

NAT
[image: NAT]

Internet Gateway
[image: Internet Gateway]

Comment: Lambda should be in private subnet. Can you verity that?

Comment: Thanks a ton Marcin, that was it. I so wish there was a facepalm smiley here to express my emotions :(

Comment: Do you want to post this as a response and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that lambda was set to be in public subnet. However, it should be in **private subnet** so that it can use NAT gateway to access internet.